# Xdebug remote debugging

Tags: xdebug

I have been trying very hard to get xdebug working. Tens of hours have been spent but still not making much progress. I think that is because there are some basic concepts being not very clear to me. One of them is "remote debugging".

Let's say I have a remote php file in VPS, if I download it and xdebug it, how does the IDE know the local file is a copy of the remote one? Can someone describe what happens when xdebugging?

What I guess is: after setting the remote port in IDE and setting browser, when I open the PHP file in the browser, when a breakpoint is reached, the IDE will establish some connection with the server and display the remote file's content in the editor. Now I can watch variables, step running functions etc, and any change I make to the file will be saved to the remote server. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

> when I open the PHP file in the browser, when a breakpoint is reached, the IDE will establish some connection with the server and display the remote file's content in the editor

That is *not* correct. The IDE does not establish the connection, but Xdebug/PHP does. The IDE acts like a *server* and listens for incoming debugging connections.

You don't mention which IDE you use, but most of them will allow you to setup a "path" mapping. Such a mapping tells the IDE how to map remote paths (the ones that PHP and Xdebug see), to the ones on your local system (the ones your IDE sees).

PHP Storm should *ask* you for a mapping if it can't find a file for example, but otherwise you can configure them yourself in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment and then the "Mappings" tab.

Other IDEs do it in other ways, but all IDEs (except Komodo) need to have the files locally available. Please note that the protocol does support only having the files remotely, but only the Komodo editor knows how to deal with that. PHP Storm does not yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still confused about one thing: do I have to have a local version of my remote site?

Comment: Yes, all IDEs (except Komodo) need to have the files locally available. (added that to my answer too)

Comment: what confused me is: If I have to have a local version, why then it is called remote debugging? why do I have to bother with things like SSH tunnel, as per https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel indicates? how is it different from just debugging on local machine?

Comment: You shouldn't need an SSH tunnel at all for this to work, unless you need to get through a firewall or through a NAT interface. "Remote" debugging is the same as debugging on a local machine, except that PHP and Xdebug are on a different machine. Please note that the protocol *does* support only having the files remotely, but only the Komodo editor knows how to deal with that. PhpStorm does not yet.

Comment: @Derick Could you point me to some documentation or explain a bit further how Komodo is doing that, please? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @shenkwen It's called remote debugging simply because it's implemented  as client (Xdebug PHP extension) / server (IDE). So to Xdebug it's still remote even if you have the IDE on the same machine as PHP. See [the documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) for details.